# Struggling to find solution: question 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone help with this problem?
$$x^2y''-7xy'+7y=13\sqrt{x}$$

---

I have brought it to its linear form and it came to this:

---

$$y''-\frac{7}{x}y'+\frac{7}{x^2}y=13\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}$$

---

Here I'm stuck, should I do reduction of order, but for that we must know one of the solutions, and I just couldn't find it.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it, it is a cauchy-euler equation, I will post the answer here if I find it, yet I would still appreciate the help.

Comment: After I find the complimentary solution, I will find the particular one via variation of parameters.

Comment: there should be a $y'$ term

Comment: Please set a meaningful title.

Comment: The equation was already in a linear form !

Comment: It is a meaningful title! And as far as I remember for the equation to be in linear form, this was necessary. Please elaborate; I don't know if I understand.

Comment: @SirDancealot: $100\%$ of the questions could have this title. (Except for the mysterious "question 3".) Be serious.

Comment: @SirDancealot: are you making fun of me ?

Comment: No! Why would I?

Comment: @SirDancealot: have you thought for a second about the information you put in the title ? Why don't you add the weather today ?

Comment: Sir, please recommend one title then. I will change it to what you say. But I thought this would be more definitive. So yes, you are right.

Comment: Consider setting a title that describes your problem. Have a look at the million titles on this site. Or use common sense.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm sorry, what do you mean by deciding on one unique sign variant?

Comment: @LutzLehmann It was supposed to be +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$x^2y''-7xy'+7y=13\sqrt{x}$$
This is Cauchy-Euler's differential equation:
$$y''-7\dfrac {(xy'-y)}{x^2}=\dfrac {13}{x\sqrt{x}}$$
$$y''-7\left (\dfrac {y}{x}\right)'=\dfrac {13}{x\sqrt{x}}$$
Integrate:
$$y'-\dfrac {7y}{x}=13\int \dfrac { \ dx}{x\sqrt{x}}$$
$$y'-\dfrac {7y}{x}=- \dfrac {26 }{\sqrt{x}}+C_1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$Y''-\frac{7}{x}Y'-\frac{7}{x^2}Y=13\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}=f(x)~~~~(1)$$
The corresponding homogeneous ODE is
$$y''-\frac{7}{x}y'-\frac{7}{x^2}y=0~~~~~~~(2)$$
Whose solution can be found by Euler's method by putting $y=x^m$, we get $m(m-1)-7m-7=0 \implies m_{1,2}=4\pm\sqrt{23}$. So two linearly independent solution of (2) are $y_1=x^{m_1}, y_2=x^{m_2}$ whose Wronskian $w(x)=y_1y'_2-y'_1y_2.$ The solution of (1) can be written by the method of variation of parameters ($C_1, C_2$) as $$Y(x)=C_1(x) y_1(x)+C_2(x) y_2(x),$$ w3here
$$C_1=-\int \frac{f(x)y_2(x)}{w(x)}~dx+D_1,~~C_2=\int \frac{f(x)y_1(x)}{w(x)} dx+ D_2.$$
Soory the numbers involved are not very good, I hope you can take it up from here.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$x=e^t$$ turns the equation to one with constant coefficients:

$$\ddot y-8\dot y+7y=13e^{t/2}.$$

The characteristic roots are $1$ and $7$. The rest is routine work.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Aryadeva I found the answer. (I like the way he has this keen eye for these questions... As if he wrote it... =_=)

---

Taking from where he left it:

First find the integrating factor of the linear ODE of:

$$y'-\dfrac {7y}{x}=- \dfrac {26 }{\sqrt{x}}+C_1$$

$$p(x)=-\frac{7}{x} $$
$$h=-7\int{\frac{1}{x}}dx$$
$$e^h=\frac{1}{x^7} $$
$$D_x[\frac{1}{x^7}y]=-26\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+c_1 $$
Take integral both sides with respect to $x$ and divide both sides by the integrating factor:
$$y=-4\sqrt{x}-8c_1\frac{1}{x}+c_2x^7 $$

Comment: You completely missed that this is a Cauchy-Euler equation, which I am sure was the topic of this exercise.